# How can I access the previous view controller from an SKScene, when it's not the rootviewcontroller and there is no navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a CollectionViewController -> GameViewController -> SKScene

In the skscene, I'm trying to show a game center leaderboard with this block of code:

```
var gcVC: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcVC.gameCenterDelegate = self
    gcVC.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.leaderboards
    gcVC.leaderboardIdentifier = "leaderboardID"
    self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(gcVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The error i get is:

2018-07-14 21:29:15.409830-0400 AppName [5266:1674334] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

If the initial view is the collectionviewcontroller, it doesn't work. If its the gameviewcontroller, it does.

I think i need to have the gameviewcontroller present the leaderboard, but i don't know how to access it.

(Keep in mind, the gameviewcontroller is not the rootviewcontroller and there is no navigation controller)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the latest presented `ViewController` from `rootViewController`,

```
if let currentVC = self.view.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.last {
    currentVC.present(gcVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much!